# PostGres Error When Using Distinct : postgres ERROR: could not identify an ordering operator for type record

Tags: postgresql, distinct

** EDIT **

Nevermind, just needed to take out the parens...

I get this error: ERROR:  could not identify an ordering operator for type record
when trying to use DISTINCT

Here's the query:

```
select DISTINCT(g.fielda, g.fieldb, r.type) 
from fields g LEFT JOIN types r ON g.id = r.id;
```

And the errors:

```
ERROR:  could not identify an ordering operator for type record
HINT:  Use an explicit ordering operator or modify the query.

********** Error **********

ERROR: could not identify an ordering operator for type record
SQL state: 42883
Hint: Use an explicit ordering operator or modify the query.
```

Comment: Please consider adding your solution as an answer, rather than editing your question, so that others can benefit from it properly :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I think you've worked out, you don't want the parentheses after `DISTINCT`.  They look like they should be parameterising `DISTINCT`, but they actually serve to make the query return a single column of record type instead of multiple columns.  The `DISTINCT` operator then tries to work on the record and finds that you've not defined an ordering on that record.

If you want `DISTINCT` to work on a subset of your return values, use `DISTINCT ON`.

Comment: Yes, I did work out the parens thing, but I didn't understand why, so thanks for the explanation!